# transpose variable amount of rows with variable amount of columns in them to <pattern> followed by all the rows till next <pattern>

Tags: perl, awk, sed, text-processing

I have the following input, related to multi-interface (dozens of them) piece of network equipment (note that the lines with `#` are for clarification only and are not present in the data):

```
eth<number1> 
# eth as pattern is fine, running number will be dealt with
parameter1 parameter2 parameter3...parameterN 
#ellipsis means and so on and is not literal
parameter21 parameter22
parameter31 parameter32 parameter33 parameter34
parameter41
eth<number2>
parameter1 parameter2
parameter21
.
.
.
.
parameterN1 parameterN2  
# again, vertical ellipsis is not literal and means simply that rows 
# with parameters can go on and on, it is not known in advance for 
# how long
eth<number3>
parameter1 parameter2
eth<number4>
parameter1 parameter2
parameter21
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
eth<number1> parameter1 parameter2 parameterN parameter21 parameter22 parameter31 parameter32 parameter33 parameter34 parameter41 
# all in one line, with as many columns as there are parameters for 
# the given interface.
eth<number2> parameter1 parameter2....parameterNM
eth<number3> parameter1 parameter2
eth<number4> parameter1 parameter2 parameter21
```

Any ideas how to accomplish it with, preferably, `awk` or `sed`? Any clarifying question are welcome, of course.

Comment: Get rid of all the `.`s in your example so we have something we can test a potential solution against and add what you have tried so far. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

This should be very easy to do in Perl. The `eth` lines are easy to match, and we just want to combine all the lines between them into a single line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $collected;
while (my $line = <DATA>){
  next if $line =~ /^#/;
  if($line =~ /^eth/) {
    # new block of lines
    if ($collected) {
      print $collected, "\n";
      $collected = "";
    }
    chomp $line;
    $collected = $line;
  } else {
    # Append to collected lines
    chomp $line;
    $collected = "$collected $line";
  }
}
print $collected,"\n" if $collected;
__DATA__
eth<number1>
parameter1 parameter2 parameter3...parameterN
#ellipsis means and so on and is not literal
parameter21 parameter22
parameter31 parameter32 parameter33 parameter34
parameter41
eth<number2>
parameter1 parameter2
parameter21
parameterN1 parameterN2
eth<number3>
parameter1 parameter2
eth<number4>
parameter1 parameter2
parameter21
```

This will parse your sample data (ignoring the comments) and create the desired output. Of course, this is just a demo; you'd want to `open` the file that the data lives in and read it:

```
open my $fh, "<", "your.data" or die "Can't open file: $!\n";
...
while(my $line = <$fh>) { 
...
```

Comment: Yes, it will do and it is clear how (will do means it is good and general enough to do it with the actual output). awk, in your opinion,  not suitable enough for this type of task ?

Comment: I'm sure it's _possible_ with `awk`, but for me it was easier to write it with Perl.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^#/d;/^eth/!{H;$!d};x;s/\n/ /gp;x;h;d' file
```

There are three scenarios: lines that begin with `#`, lines that begin `eth and other lines.

If the current line is a comment, delete it.

If the current line does not begin `eth`, append it to the hold space (HS) and delete it unless it is the last line.

Otherwise, the current line begins `eth` or is the last line, so swap to the HS and if that contains any linefeeds, replace them with spaces and print the result. Swap back to the pattern space and replace the HS with the current line and delete the current line unless it is the last line of the file in which case print it.

Comment: This is very elegant!

Comment: Maybe (and quite probably) I was not clear enough and I am sorry about it but <number1> is not literal in the sense that there are no <...> to be found in the input -- I attempted to represent running number of the given interface. In hard reality it looks like: eth 1-43 ; eth 1-44; eth 2-36; eth 2-37 and so on and what is represented as parameter<number> below these lines in principle CAN very well contain the same numerical pattern.

Comment: @protong -- OK, I am still digesting sed incantation (including notion of HS), however, what very clearly happens is that last line (row) is both transposed to last  column<s> for the last eth entry and also is printed as the last line. So, in the example input it would be parameter21 both as a last column for the line containing eth<number4>  and also printed out as a separate line. You can try it yourself.

Comment: @potong, just got some spare minutes -- it still prints it twice. Example input is representative enough.